# Default Probability estimation

Tags: credit-risk, default-probability

Can you please provide some workout references on how to estimate the `Default probability for Wholesale portfolio?`

How does it defer from Retail portfolio case?

I am aware of the estimation of the same using Merton model. Is it for retail portfolio or wholesale portfolio? or can be used for both?

Your insight will be very appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more context. What do you mean by Wholesale v. Retail portfolio?

Comment: I use standard definition - https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/wholesalebanking.asp